# Who can list more strings from given alphabets?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem, combinatorics-on-words

This is a question that was asked by one of the members but was down-voted as he did not show his attempt to solve it. He added that later and the down-votes were taken back. I answered the question but for some reason, OP deleted the post quickly after that so I could not add any comments. As I was solving the problem, I found something interesting that I wanted some insights on and that is the reason, I am posting it with additional details.

**Question:**
Person $1$ lists all possible strings of length $2x$, such that each letter is one of $A, B$, and each string containts the same number of $A's$ and $B's$.

Person $2$ lists all possible strings of length $x$, such that each letter is one of $A, B, C, D$ and each string contains the same number of $A's$ and $B's$ ($A = B = 0$ or $C = 0$, $D = 0$ are allowed).

**My solution:**

Person $1$:
Number of strings of length $2x$ from equal numbers of $A$ and $B$ ($x$ each) $ = M(2x) = \dfrac {(2x)!}{x!x!}$, ($x \in \mathbb {Z+}$)

Person $2$:

we can start from $A = B = 0$. Each alphabet in the string can have value of $C$ or $D$ independently.

$N(0) = 2^x$

For $A = B = 1, N(1) = {^x}P_2 \times 2^{x-2}$

For $A = B = 2, N(2) = \dfrac {{^x}P_4}{2!2!} \times 2^{x-4}$

For $A = B = k, 2k \le x, N(k) = \dfrac {{^x}P_{2k}}{k!k!} \times 2^{x-2k}$

Say, $n = \left\lfloor\dfrac{x}{2}\right\rfloor$, where $n$ is the largest integer lower than or equal to $\dfrac{x}{2}$.

$N(x) = \sum \limits_{k = 0}^{n}N(k) = \sum \limits_{k = 0}^{n} \dfrac {{^x}P_{2k}}{k!k!} \times 2^{x-2k}$

I checked and noticed $M(2x) = N(x)$ for $2 \le x \le 5$.

**So the question I have, is it only happening for smaller values of $x$ or is the below true?**

$\sum \limits_{k = 0}^{n} \dfrac {{^x}P_{2k}}{k!k!} \times 2^{x-2k} = \dfrac {(2x)!}{x!x!}$, where $n$ is the largest integer lower than or equal to $\dfrac{x}{2}$.

**If it is true, please share some references or hint on how I should proceed with the proof.**

Comment: What is the initial definition of $N(x)$?

Comment: Consider a length $n$ string with the four letters with the properties you say.  For ease of telling apart, let's use capital letters here.  So for example `AACBCBD`.  Let us map this string to a length $2n$ string using only `a`'s and `b`'s by taking `A` and replacing with `aa`, taking `B` and replacing with `bb`, taking `C` and replacing with `ab` and taking `D` and replacing with `ba`... so the string `AACBCBD` maps to `aaaaabbbabbbba` for instance.  Can you show that is a bijection between the sets?

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks. Yes based on similar hint from Ross Millikan, I was able to go ahead and prove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a bijection between the two.  Take a string of length $2x$ and break it into pairs of letters.  Replace $AA$ with $A$, $BB$ with $B$, $AB$ with $C$ and $BA$ with $D$.  You create a matching string of length $x$ with an equal number of $A$s and $B$s.

Comment: thank you  That's a good point and makes sense. That is why I am getting equal value from both in my approach too but how do I proceed to prove they are the same? I tried induction method with $x$ and $x+1$.

Comment: @MathLover:  this is a (sketch of a) proof.  I have indicated how to match up the two sets of strings.  To fill it out, it is clear that every string of length $2x$ generates one string of length $x$.  We need to argue that it gets every allowed string of length $x$ and that the generated strings satisfy the requirement that the number of $A$s equals the number of $B$s.  The second part comes from the fact that there must be an equal number of $AA$s and $BB$s in the first string so that the total count of $A$s equals the number of $B$s.

Comment: yes I realized after my comment. Let me do it. Thanks.